# Subspace. Function.

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the subset $ B$ of vector space $ F(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ the subspace of this vector space?;
$ B=\{f: f(7)=2+f(1)\}$

My prove:

let $g(x),h(x) \subset B$

1) $(\alpha*g)(7)=\alpha * g(7) =\alpha *(2+g(1))=2*\alpha+ (\alpha*g)(1) \not\subset B $

2) $(g+h)(7)=g(7)+h(7)=4 + g(2) +h(2) = 4 + (h+g)(2) \not\subset B  $

To show that it's not a subspace it's enough to prove that one of conditions 1),2) is false and both are false, so $B$ is not a subspace of $ F(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$.

Is it correct?

Comment: Don't say $g(x)\subset B$, say $g\in B$. And don't say $2\alpha+(\alpha g)(1)\not\subset B$, say $2\alpha+(\alpha g)(1)\ne 2+(\alpha g)(1)$ (which leads you to choosing $\alpha\ne1$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to show that it is not a subspace it is enough to show that for a  $f\in B$ ,$\alpha f\notin B$ for a suitable $\alpha\in \Bbb R$.

Define $f(1)=1;f(7)=3$ and $f(x)=2\forall x\neq 1,7$.

$f(7)=3=2+f(1)$

Take $\alpha=2$,then $2f(1)=2;2f(7)=6,2f(x)=4\forall x\neq 1,7$

Then $2f(7)=6\neq2+2f(1)=2+2=4$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: does the constant zero function satisfy the relation?

Comment: No it doesn't. If B is a subspace f(0) must be in B (null vector). Is it enough as a counterexample?

Comment: @NowakGrzegorz Not $f(0)$, but the constant zero function. Yes, it is enough.